# Is there a way to download nuget.exe and then do an offline upgradation into the Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nuget

My visual studio is installed on a machine which doesn't have internet connection so I can't upgrade the NuGet Manager in VS.
I am looking for a way to use another machine which has internet connection to download NuGet Manager exe and then install on VS.

**Updated**

please check below screen print which i have installed on the my machine.also please note that i don`t have internet connection on that machine. so i can not upgrade NuGet manager from Visual studio.

[image]

can anybody help me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to download nuget.exe and then do an offline upgradation into the Visual Studio?

The answer is yes. But if you want to  upgrade the **NuGet Manager in Visual Studio 2015**, you should download the NuGet extension for Visual Studio instead of `nuget.exe`:

**Visual Studio 2015**: https://dist.nuget.org/visualstudio-2015-vsix/latest/NuGet.Tools.vsix

Before upgrade the extension, you should uninstall the old version by `Tools`->`Extension and Updates...`->`Installed`->`NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio`, then restart Visual Studio, install that extension.

If you are using **Visual Studio 2017**, you should download the upgrade Visual Studio instead of `nuget.exe`.

**Reason:**

> NuGet Package Manager 4.x (PM UI and PM Console) are included with
>   Visual Studio 2017 (all 15.x versions). Latest NuGet releases are
>   delivered as part of Visual Studio updates.
>
> Note: nuget.exe itself is not included with any version of Visual
>   Studio.

**Update:**

Since you are using Visual Studio 2010 with nuget manager 2.0.3 and you do not have the internet connection on that machine, you can try to uninstall that nuget manager, download the latest version from other machine, then install it. Or you can install that extension directly.

Source: [NuGet Package Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuGetTeam.NuGetPackageManager)

Since I do not use such version Visual Studio, I am not sure if you can uninstall it or update it directly. If not, I am afraid you have to download the Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate version, then install it on that machine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Leo!, but we have Visual studio 2010 which we can`t upgrade to the latest version due to the project requirement.

Comment: @NitinJain, If you are using Visual studio 2010, the latest NuGet package Manager version is 2.8.6. You cannot upgrade to a higher version except upgrade Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes you are right, but currently on my machine NuGet Package Manager version is 2.0.3. which i want to upgrade with 2.8.6. so can you please help on this?

Comment: @NitinJain, I have updated the answer, you can check if the update info is helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Leo Liu-MSFT for give your time and looking into the my issue.
Please check my updated details above.

Comment: @NitinJain, you are always welcome :). Thanks for your update, I forgot that you can not have internet connection on that machine. Could you please uninstall that nuget manager from the Tools menu select Extensions and Updates, if yes, you can uninstall it, then install the latest extension, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuGetTeam.NuGetPackageManager. Since I do not have install that version VS2010, I could not give you the solution directly, just some advises, very sorry for this.

Comment: @NitinJain, Again, update my answer, you can check if it helps.

Comment: @NitinJain - what's the project requirement? Visual Studio 2010 was the first version where they started caring a lot about *round-tripping* between versions of visual studio, so later versions of VS should be able to load 2010 solutions without having to upgrade them.